# What is wrong in the congruence of the triangles?

Tags: geometry

I have an isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$.

In my development, I have obtained that the parallel sides are equal. But that is impossible, because if that happened, it would be a parallelogram.

So, what is the error in my development? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Basically, $DC$ can't be equal to $AB$, so what is my mistake?

Comment: What are you trying to prove about this trapezoid?

Comment: nothing, but in my development, the paralallel sides are equal, and it is impossible because in that case, it can be a parallelogram

Comment: @Mattiu The two angles that you labeled $\,\alpha\,$ are not equal.

Comment: why? if is trapezoid ab and cd are parallel

Comment: AD and BC are not parallel; in the two alpha angles, AC is a transversal, and if you wanted those marked angles to be equal, you'd want AD and CB to be parallel. But here we have AB and CD are parallel, and nothing about AD and CB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you given those angles are equal?

If so then the trapezoid *IS* a parallelogram that is not drawn to scale. (Who told you that the trapezoid *wasn't* a parallelogram?)

The angles marked $\beta$ must be equal because $\overline{DC}$ is parallel to $\overline{AB}$.  But the angles marked $\alpha$  are equal if and only if $\overline{AD}$ is parallel to $\overline{BC}$.

Which if this is drawn to scale they are not; but which otherwise you have no reason to rule out.

=====

Ah.  I see.  $\angle DCA = \beta$ but $\angle ACB \ne \alpha$.

Because it is a isoceles trapezoid the *base* angles are congruent.  Then base angles are $\angle ABC$ and $\angle DAB$ so $\angle ABC = \angle DAB =\alpha + \beta$.

$\angle DBC$ is *NOT* a base angle. And $\angle DBC \ne \angle DAB$ (even though $\angle DCA =  \beta$.)

Answer (score 1):

Peter's right that you don't have similar triangles, but here's another way to check. A sanity check, if you will.

A defining characteristic of similar triangles is that their angles have the same measures. It's easy to see that $\triangle ACD$ has an obtuse angle, while $\triangle CAB$ does not. Therefore, there's no way the two can be similar.

Comment: A good point! (+1)

Answer (score 0):

The angle $\alpha$ does not occur twice because $AD$ and $BC$ are not parallel.

Hence you do not have similar triangles.

Comment: why? in a isosceles trapezoid exist one pair of sides are parallel and the other are congruent

Comment: @Mattiu  Sorry, I mixed the letters. Fixed